# How to filter in Power Automate a query from a SharePoint list by a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, filter, office365, lookup, power-automate

I'm learning Power Automate and trying to get items from a SharePoint list filtered by a lookup column.

The SharePoint list columns are:
[image: Columns]

This flow will execute when a new item is added to the list and when this happens the user will have to provide a value to the field TallerRelacionado which is an item of another list.
And in Get items I'm trying to filter in this way:
[image: Get items]

TallerRelacionado -eq TallerRelacionado Value

But I'm getting 0 rows in the output. If you can help me I would be so grateful.

Comment: Try changing this to "TallerRelacionado/Title eq 'TallerRelacionado Value'".

Comment: That's it! It works now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I fixed it was changing "TallerRelacionado/Title eq 'TallerRelacionado Value'" as Sarah Cox said in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this to "TallerRelacionado/Title eq 'TallerRelacionado Value'".